# How to store input text as variable and use it to identify which element to be used on next test case

Tags: robotframework

User input text when creating a folder and the folder name is stored as a variable for next test case.

The current test case uses a hardcoded folder name, I would want to use it dynamically.

Test case 1: how to store the value `Folder Test W1`

```
*** Test Cases ***
001_Save_Folder
     Click World Name
     Keyboard Input    insertText    Folder Test W1
     Click Save
```

Test case 2:

```
*** Test Cases ***
001_Delete_Folder
     Select Folder and Click Delete
     Click OK
```

The element (delete button) to delete the specific folder.

how to parse the variable to let the robot know which folder to select

```
${Delete-THIS-folder}               //td[text()='Folder Test W1']/following-sibling::td[.//span[@aria-label='delete']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Got a solution by creating parameter:

```
*** Test Cases ***
001_Save_Folder
    Click World Name
    Keyboard Input    insertText    ${WorldName}
    Click Save
```

Then element:

```
${Delete-THIS-Map}               //td[text()='${WorldName}']/following-sibling::td[.//span[@aria-label='delete']]
```